# how to match the shape of the area with the object on the android camera using computer vision?

Tags: android, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

hello friends wherever you are,

[image]

I want to try to match the object to the template in front of the android camera using OpenCv and tensorflow and then if the recognized object matches then the lines in the template change color (like the example picture above).

So the question is how to recognize the shape of the object and compare it to the template?
And what is the best method to do this or what should I learn ?

I've searched google but haven't found the right keywords.

Thank you

Comment: If its always an object on a white background could you do a bit of image manipulation to get a high contrast black and white image that you can use to draw the outline?

Comment: You can look into thresholding for image segmentation

Comment: This question is very broad. Please read [ask]. It's not clear what kind of answer you're expecting. Just the keywords to search in the net? What have you tried so far? Which programming language do you use in your project? As you are talking about templates which kinds of templates do you have? Can you please edit your question to a specific programming problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer?